# Express.js req.body prints undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const  express = require('express')
const userRouter= require('./routes/user.js')
const User = require('./models/user.js')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
  
app.use(userRouter)

 const router = new express.Router()

 app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
     debugger
    console.log('Hello')
     res.send('Hello World')
 })



app.post('/clients',async (req,res)=>{
    const user = new User(req.body)
    debugger
    try{
        console.log("body "+req.body)
       var result = await  user.save()
        res.status(201).send(result)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})


app.use(router);


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('Server started at'+port)
})
```

the /clients endpoint prints req.body undefined
i have tried all the cases but still unable to find the error

> 1.used //app.use(express.json) but didnt work for me

> 2. when i print req in browser console iam unable to find body param in req object

Comment: How are you testing the `/clients` endpoint?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense. What do you do to make sure `/clients` works?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just saving user info into mongodb. and payload as follows.{
 "name":"james",
 "age":28,
 "mobile":"990884",
 "email":"jamaes@gmail.com",
 "password":"james"
}

Comment: Do you use a browser to test it? or Postman? or another program?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i used postman to test it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

instead of `urlencoded`

More info - https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions

Please set JSON(application/json)
[image: Please select JSON(application/json) as shown in image]

Comment: // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
>app.use(bodyParser.json()), i tried but didn't work for me

Comment: i able to send payload from postman and it returns me validation error which i have kept for user model. the issue is with req.body. i couldn't find body when i print req in brower console. any idea ?

Comment: If you are using version greater than  Express v4.16.0 you can remove body-parser and try app.use(express.json());
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: even tried app.use(express.json()) didn't work for me